# How can I fix the syntax error in this simple JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

What's wrong with my code? Dreamweaver keeps telling me I have a syntax error!

```
function myFunction(); {
    var a = 5;
    var b = 10;
    var c = 15;
    var d = a + b + c;
    alert("The value of d is: " + d);
}
```

The error tells me that the syntax error with the function `myFunction();` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added an unnessesary semicolon after myFunction()

function myFunction() **;** <== here {

Answer (score 0):

You have a semicolon after the function signature.  Should be:

```
function myFunction() {
  var a = 5;
  var b = 10;
  var c = 15;
  var d = a+b+c;
  alert("The value of d is: " + d);
}
```

Also for future reference, run your code through http://jslint.com for more detailed error messages.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one issue and that is the semicolon used after the function name.
Try this:

```
function myFunction() {

 var a = 5;
 var b = 10;
 var c = 15;
 var d = a+b+c;
 alert("The value of d is: " + d);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver is correct you have a bad semicolon which terminates the function before you open the function body (immediately after you declare it)

```
function myFunction(); {
```

remove it like

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = 5;
  var b = 10;
  var c = 15;
  var d = a + b + c;
  alert("The value of d is: " + d);
}
myFunction();
```